# Differences: iBeacon & Beacon

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am studying beacon.

When I develop beacon signal, I noticed some beacon signal is iBeacon but some signal is not.

And I guess, this situation occurs from `company_identifier` (BLE type should be 02)

If my guessing is not, is there any structure for iBeacon?

I mean, is there any profile that classify iBeacon and just beacon? (in UUID, Major, Minor Feild)

Comment: plus, Every iBeacon should have 128-bits UUID?

Comment: Can you post the full afvertisement packet you are broadcasting?  Then we may be able to tell you if it is compliant or not. If you sign up for Apple's MFI iBeacon programme they will give you access to the spec., if not there are numerous sources where it has been reverse engineered.

Answer (score 4):

Bluetooth low energy devices (Beacon) can operate in an advertisement mode to notify nearby devices of their presence.
The Only difference between iBeacon and other standardized beacons should only be the prefix bytes:

"02 01 06 1a ff 4c 00 02 15  # Apple's fixed iBeacon advertising prefix".

Check further information in [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBeacon).

Answer (score 0):

When a Beacon is iBeacon it means the beacon use the iBeacon protocol for iOS 7+ which you can find more about that [here](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/)

However a Beacon could use any beacon protocol like  Eddystone beacon which means it use the Eddystone protocol from google you can find more about this protocol [here](https://developers.google.com/beacons/)

Now, comparing those two protocols I can tell few differences:

Beacon Eddystone: the packets it get sent is Id, Url, sensor telemetry "beacon health data"

iBeacon: the packet it get sent is UUID, majorId, minorId

Beacon Eddystone : sends a Url that open in your mobile browser if you activated the physical web option.

iBeacon: sends UUID which can be used to deliver a content

Beacon Eddystone : require no app
iBeacon: require an app